# Creating a matrix of variable dimension and then creating an algorithm to assign its values in python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to create a list of variable dimension (n+1)x(n+1) in python, then assign values into the entries. Specifically, I want the first row to be a previously defined list. Creating the variable dimension matrix is quite easy:

```
import numpy as np

def m(n): #m is our nxn matrix
 return np.empty(shape=(n+1,n+1), dtype=float)
for j in range(n+1): #we want to fill the entire 0th row with 2
  m(n)[0][j]=2
```

Wanted output for n=3:

```
array([[ 2,  2,  2,  2],
   [-3.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 3., -6.,  3.,  0.],
   [-1.,  3., -3.,  1.]])
```

Actual output:

```
array([[ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [-3.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 3., -6.,  3.,  0.],
   [-1.,  3., -3.,  1.]])
```

My end-goal is to say:

```
for j in range(n+1): 
  m(n)[0][j]= list[j]#where list[j] has n+1 entires
```

That is, to fill the 0th row with a list containing n+1 values. I'm quite new to python, so any help is very much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for j in range(n+1):
>     m(n)[0][j]=2
> ```

will create plenty of ndarrays and throw them away - you never STORE the resulting thing from `m(n)` call - you create it, modify it and throw it away

You do not need any loops or algorythms to set the first row.
I suggest using `np.zeros` instead of `np.empty` - empty will have "something" in it, zeros nulls it:

```
import numpy as np

def m(nnnn): # m is our nxn matrix
    # np.empty does not set any values - start with zeros instead
    return np.zeros(shape=(nnnn+1,nnnn+1), dtype=float)

n = 3
whatever = m(3)
whatever[0,] = 2 # set the first row with values of 2 using indexing
    
print(whatever)  # 1

# [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
some_3x3 = np.array(range(1,10)).reshape((3,3)) 

# set lower part of your 4x4 with that:
whatever[1:,0:3] = some_3x3 

print(whatever) # 2
```

To get:

```
# 1 
[[2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]

# 2 
[[2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [1. 2. 3. 0.]
 [4. 5. 6. 0.]
 [7. 8. 9. 0.]]
```

With `np.empty` you'll get something like:

```
[[2.00000000e+000 2.00000000e+000 2.00000000e+000 2.00000000e+000]
 [1.69119330e-306 1.78022342e-306 6.89810244e-307 8.90071135e-308]
 [6.23037657e-307 6.23053954e-307 9.34609790e-307 8.45593934e-307]
 [9.34600963e-307 1.86921143e-306 6.23061763e-307 8.90029544e-307]]
```

Comment: you were completely right, the most important part was saving the output. Again, thank you!